# Selenium web crawling in a Cloud Foundry app

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm new trying to deploy a **Cloud Foundry app** (Python runtime) on IBM Cloud.

The app needs to crawl a dynamic website and upload the contents at another location.

I'm using Selenium with headless Firefox webdriver to achieve this on my local.

I packaged the geckodriver binary along with my app and provided the path to the binary inside my python code. As expected though, when deployed on CF, the app isn't able to launch a Firefox instance and gives a **SessionNotCreatedException**.

Is it possible to use Selenium on a CF deployed app? What would I need to do to make it work? Will Firefox portable help?

Also, is there any other (better) way to scrape a dynamically generated website with a python CF app?

Thanks!

Code goes like this:

```
from flask import Flask
import atexit
import os
import traceback
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
client = None
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

   
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')

@app.route('/fetch')
def fetch():
    url = 'http://www.python.org' #Placeholder url
    try:
        dr_path = os.path.join(APP_ROOT,'geckodriver')
        #This causes exception
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = dr_path, firefox_options=options)
        driver.get(url)
        html_src = driver.page_source
        #Scrape content
        return scraped_content
    except:
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        return 'Exception:\n' + str(tb)

port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 8000))

@atexit.register
def shutdown():
    if client:
        client.disconnect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

The exception generated is:

`selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities`

Comment: One question, one answer. Is your app a web app or standalone (server)? Provide details and code / config on what you did and detailed error messages

Comment: It's a web app (Python Flask), deployed on IBM Cloud as a Cloud Foundry service. Added code to the question.